# How to convert second into datetime's 108 format hh:mm:ss in sql server without writing function

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
    select v1.*, datediff(ss,v1.dateofchange,v2.dateofchange) as acutaltime 
from vActualTime v1 left join vActualTime v2
    on v1.rowno=v2.rowno-1 

FK_PatientId FK_Status_PatientId DateofChange            rowno                acutaltime
------------ ------------------- ----------------------- -------------------- -----------
3            16                  2010-08-02 15:43:46.000 1                    757
3            24                  2010-08-02 15:56:23.000 2                    96
3            26                  2010-08-02 15:57:59.000 3                    NULL
```

I am using Sql server 2005

When I writes this

```
    select v1.*, datediff(mi,v1.dateofchange,v2.dateofchange) as acutaltime,
    convert(datetime,datediff(mi,v1.dateofchange,v2.dateofchange),108) as [date] 
from vActualTime v1 left join vActualTime v2
    on v1.rowno=v2.rowno-1
```

I gets this

```
FK_PatientId FK_Status_PatientId DateofChange            rowno                acutaltime  date
------------ ------------------- ----------------------- -------------------- ----------- -----------------------
3            16                  2010-08-02 15:43:46.000 1                    13          1900-01-14 00:00:00.000
3            24                  2010-08-02 15:56:23.000 2                    1           1900-01-02 00:00:00.000
3            26                  2010-08-02 15:57:59.000 3                    NULL        NULL
```

This should have been given as 00-00-000 00:13:00:0000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand you need to take your calculated minutes (the datediff you're doing) and display that in a time format 108.

This should convert the minutes to a datetime format of 108, i.e. hh:mm:ss

```
select convert(varchar
              ,dateadd(minute
                      , datediff(mi,v1.dateofchange,v2.dateofchange), '00:00:00')
              , 108
              )
```

Comment: Wow this works great and simple in understanding. I was about to create a function for doing the same thing. ty

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't.

Long answer:

First, the calculated value in minutes is interpreted as days in the CONVERT function. You'd need to divide by (24 * 60) to actually add minutes.

DATETIME only covers the years 1753 to 9999 ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277%28SQL.80%29.aspx)). Note the statement

> Microsoft® SQL Server™ rejects all values it cannot recognize as dates between 1753 and 9999.

Even if you use DATETIME2 (requiring SQL Server 2008?), your date intervall only starts with the year 1. ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx))

Sql2008 adds a new data type called [TIME](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3718086/New-datetime-datatypes-in-SQL-Server-2008.htm), which might solve your problem.